# How to display Django array data

Tags: arrays, django, postgresql

I am using Django and PostgreSQL. I have inserted some data into the models array field. My models are like

```
class PurchaseInvoice(models.Model):
    invoice = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    product_name = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=500))
    price = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=300))
    quantity = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200))
    amount = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=300))
```

I have inserted data successfully, but when I try to query my data I get like **["['LNB Inverto', 'Dish']"]**. I want to view my data in an HTML table. My *views.py* file is as the following:

```
def purchaseDetails(request,pk):
    invo_data = PurchaseInvoice.objects.filter(invoice=pk)
    return render(request,'purchase/invoice_details.html',{'invoice':invo_data})
```

And my HTML tables like:

```
{% for data in invoice %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{data.product_name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.price}}</td>
        <td>{{data.quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
{% for data in invoice %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {% for name in data.product_name %}
                {{ name }}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
        <td>{{ data.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

###### happy coding :)

Comment: I got   **['LNB Inverto', 'Dish']**

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following code. Your code is almost 100% right, I think,  but I don’t know why the query returns like this: ["['LNB Inverto', 'Dish']"].

```
PurchaseInvoice.objects.all().filter(invoice=pk)
```

So try to do this query. Maybe your problem will be solved.

Comment: ca you project file with me i check it